# AJAX Div Retrieval every 60 seconds

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, refresh

What I would like to do is retrieve the contents of a PHP file and insert it into a div every 60 seconds, basically refreshing the dynamic div. I've come up with the following code so far, however it doesn't seem to be working. The code is just like this, nothing extra, apart from the MYSQL login.

PHP to grab:

```
<?php                   
$time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time());
                mysql_query("UPDATE djs SET requesttime='{$time}' WHERE username='{$djs['username']}'")
                or die(mysql_error()); 

                $request_db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM requests
                WHERE haveplayed='0'") or die(mysql_error());  
                echo "<table style=\"border:1px solid;width:99%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;\" border=\"1\">";
                echo "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th><th>Dedicated To...</th></tr>";
                while($request = mysql_fetch_array( $request_db )) {
                    echo "<tr><td style=\"width:33%;padding:1px;\">";
                    echo $request['SongName'];  
                    echo "</td><td style=\"width:33%;\">";
                    echo $request['Artist'];    
                    echo "</td><td style=\"width:33%;\">";
                    echo $request['DedicatedTo'];
                    echo "</td></tr>";  
                }
                echo "</table>";
            ?>
```

The original PHP code is just the same, enclosed in a div with an id attribute of 'ajax_table'.

The JavaScript is:

```
// JavaScript Document
var xmlHttp_moniter

function moniter()
{
    xmlHttp_moniter = GetXmlHttpObject_parcel()
if(xmlHttp_moniter == null)
{
    alert("browser does not support HTTP Request")
    return
}
var url="ajax_table.php?random=" + Math.random()
xmlHttp_moniter.onreadystatechange = stateChanged
xmlHttp_moniter.open("GET",url,true)
xmlHttp_moniter.send(null)

}

function stateChanged()
{
if(xmlHttp_moniter.readyState==4 || xmlHttp_moniter.readyState == "complete")
{
    document.getElementById("ajax_table").innerHTML = xmlHttp_moniter.responseText
    setTimeout('ajax_table()',60000);
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject_parcel()
{
var xmlHttp_moniter=null;
try
{
    xmlHttp_moniter=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e)
     {
         //Internet Explorer
         try
          {
              xmlHttp_moniter=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          }
         catch (e)
          {
          xmlHttp_moniter=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
     }
return xmlHttp_moniter;
}
```

and that is on the page that is requesting the other php page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a framework like jQuery to simplify your javascript:

```
$(function() {

  setInterval(function() {
    $.get('ajax_table.php', function(data) {
      $('#ajax_table').html(data);
    });
  }, 60 * 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, there's no js function ajax_table() called in

```
setTimeout('ajax_table()',60000);
```

in your code.

At second point, are you sure you are calling moniter() function somewhere for the first time?

Comment: Thanks! The first time I've changed moniter to ajax_table, what else do I need to do?

Comment: Still doesn't work? Code is incomplete, so I can only guess.
1) You have to add first timer after page load so the first request will be executed (ugly and simple: <body onload="setTimeout('ajax_table()',60000);" ...
2) is the url variable from xmlHttp_moniter.open("GET",url,true) set anywhere?
3) Check firebug console output (or some similar tool) for any errors.
4) Check if request are done (firebug)
5) Check content of requests. (Does server side script return expected content?)

Basicaly your script should work when points 1) and 2) are fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You can retrieve the contents of a PHP file and insert it into a div for every 60 seconds http://www.webtrickss.com/ajax/how-to-refresh-a-div-using-ajax/